# changing a header color by clicking on an anchor href

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, html-lists

I'm trying to make a nav bar which will be fixed to the side of the page with an unordered list. The list items will link down the page via anchor.

However, I want an h2 element to change colors based on which element in the fixed nav bar is clicked on.

For example: When "home" is clicked in the nav it will anchor down the page to the id #home and then also change the h2 color to an active color. THEN when "about us" is clicked in the nav, it needs to remove the active color from #home, and add it to #about.

This requires both adding and removing classes through jquery (maybe??) but I just don't know enough. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo8ceL19/3/) to get my point across.

This is my current jquery script which will not be able to add a color to an active anchor:

```
$('#header li a').on('click', function() {
 $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
 $('#1').addClass('current');});
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass('current');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#1` is in your href and not an id of the link. Using `this` will get you what was clicked on.

Now if you want alter the headers, you would need to select it with the hash

```js
$('#header li a').on('click', function() {
  $('li a.current, h2.current').removeClass('current');       //remove the current class from the link and h2
  $(this).addClass('current'); //add current to the link that was clicked
  $(this.hash).addClass('current');  //add class to h2 using the hash which  gives you the #1, #2 in the href of the link
});
```

```css
a.current {
   background-color: yellow;  
}

h2.current {
    background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">directors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">admissions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 id="1">home</h2>
  <h2 id="2">about us</h2>
  <h2 id="3">directors</h2>
  <h2 id="4">admissions</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! Here's a follow up question, just because I'm curious: if I had the <h2> tags in an iframe pulling from another page call it "home.html", "aboutus.html"...so on. How would this code need to be modified/ is that possible to function?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the color of h2 element that has the same id as given in the link you can use:

```
$('#header li a').on('click', function() {
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('current');
});
```